# Mean of values Monthly in Dataframe with date as column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

Thanks for investing time to help me out :)

I have DataFrame (df_NSE_Price_) like below:

```
Company Name                ID      2000-01-03 00:00:00 2000-01-04 00:00:00 ....
Reliance Industries Ltd.    100325  50.810              54.
Tata Consultancy Service    123455  123                 125
..
```

I would want output like below :

```
Company Name                ID      March 00   April 00 .....
Reliance Industries Ltd    100325   52         55
Tata Consultancy Services  123455   124.3      124
..
```

The output data has to have the average of data month wise.

So far i have tried

`df_NSE_Price_.resample('M',axis=1).mean()`

But this gave me error
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: Question is unclear, can you add a sample input and output and explain how to reach the output from input.

Comment: hey sorry i edited the answer for better explanation

Comment: How do you get 52 for March 00 could you explain?

Comment: as mentioned its mean for the entire month

Comment: Does this mean, on your NSE_Price df, the columns represent days?

Comment: yes it represents days with dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I converted the data to a Data Frame (I added a column with February info, too).

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ('Company Name', 
           'ID', 
           '2000-01-03 00:00:00', 
           '2000-01-04 00:00:00', 
           '2000-02-04 00:00:00')

data = [('Reliance Industries Ltd.', 100325, 50.810, 54., 66.0),
        ('Tata Consultancy Service', 123455, 123, 125, 130.0),]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

Second, I created a two-level index (MultiIndex), using Company and ID.  Now, all column labels are dates.  Then, I converted the column labels to date format (using `.to_datetime()`

```
df = df.set_index(['Company Name', 'ID'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

Third, I re-sampled in monthly intervals, using the 'axis=1' to aggregate by column.  This creates one month per column.  Convert from month-end dates to periods with 'to_period()':

```
df = df.resample('M', axis=1).sum()
df.columns = df.columns.to_period('M')

                                 2000-01  2000-02
Company Name             ID                      
Reliance Industries Ltd. 100325   104.81     66.0
Tata Consultancy Service 123455   248.00    130.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:
df.transpose().resample('M',axis=1).mean().transpose()

Comment: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex' > gave the same error